# Rails select_tag problem in show and index actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, html-select

I have a select_tag to pick items from a list here's the code:

```
<%= select_tag "Drinks", options_for_select([ "Water", "Soda", "Beer" ], "Water") %>
```

After submiting "water" for exemple, it doesn't show up on the index and show views, on the "Drinks" section.

What am I doing wrong?

Controllers create and update methods

```
def create
    @facture = Facture.new(params[:facture])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @facture.save
        format.html { redirect_to @facture, :notice => 'Facture was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @facture, :status => :created, :location => @facture }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @facture.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


def update
    @facture = Facture.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @facture.update_attributes(params[:facture])
        format.html { redirect_to @facture, :notice => 'Facture was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @facture.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: code that u are showing is it of a index and show?

Comment: the actual code is off  "_form.html.erb"

Comment: Please post the create/update code from your controller

Comment: I have put the create and update controller in the question area

Comment: Can you also post the full form and your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
select_tag "facture[drinks]", options_for_select([ "Water", "Soda", "Beer" ], "Water")
```

The create method is using the values sent in params[:facture] and using "facture[drinks]" will include it as params[:facture][:drinks].

Comment: De nada amigo, it happened to me a lot...remember to always document your issue solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I proceed(thanks to miligraf):

1- let the code in controllers/factures intact

2- change the code in views/factures/_form.html.erb:

**before**

```
<%= select_tag "facture", options_for_select([ "Water", "Soda", "Beer" ], "Water") %>
```

**after**

```
<%= select_tag "facture[drinks]", options_for_select([ "Water", "Soda", "Beer" ], "Water") %>
```